# How to find and script database objects in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to script all database objects with a specific string in object's Name, Could not find any code snippet to script database objects with search function.

SSMS does not allow for search.

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want to do ? maybe give example.

Comment: Just do the lot to a file and them mine that. Make sure you deal with dependencies.

Comment: @TwTw, basically this is a big ERP database with thousands of objects, we prefix new objects with our company's name to help us identify. I just want to get all of these.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, I did not get you, can you elaborate please .

Comment: Script everything to a file, then extract the bits you want from the file with some sort of text finder is what I was suggesting, however it doesn't appear to be what you need. Finding objects with names like '%Acme%' is a trivial problem in comparison to scripting out objects and their dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the database name, then select Task, then select Generate Scipts, then Next, select that you want all object scripts or select the objects that you want, then decide where do you want to get the results (in the Advanced tab you can select that you want to have an all data from the database), then Next and Next.

You will have an option to select the object name that you want to have.

Edit: of course if you want to have a dynamic option for solve your problems it's possible, but more complex.

You can get all of your objects with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Your database name].sys.all_objects
```

Of course if you want to have just the objects with specific name you can add a "where" statement to get what you need
Than you should write a scripts to get a definitione of each object type. For example in the case of stored procedurę it's quite simple:

```
sp_helptext [your_stored_procedure_text]
```

If you want to get the create table script you will need more complex query, but you can find tchem in the net.

Hope this is helpful for you

Comment: I do not find that option where i can select objects name, can you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: WIth the first option (generating scripts from Management Studio) you can just select the name of table as the main object. Than in advanced option you can point that you want to have a stored procedures and indexes for this tables. You can always generate scripts and then parse the results and get what you want. Otherwise you will need to write your own query.